# ¿ como podría reducir el peso de una imagen subida a node.js?

Tags: nodejs, imagen, optimizar

Planteamiento del problema: Lo que quiero es reducir el PESO mas no redimensionar o cambiar el tamaño de la imágen, es decir, si una imagen subida pesa 5 mb lo quieero es reducir ese peso lo máximo posible, si es Kb sería lo ideal.

Tengo un rato leyendo y buscando información, he encontrado módulos como sharop o jimp pero veo que lo que hacen es modificar el tamaño de la imagén, mas no reducir u optimizar el peso.

Existe una forma de reducir el peso de una imagen en Node.js ? estoy trabajando con Angular en el front, y biscamente lo que quiero hacer es subir la imagen al back, y luego, desde el back (Node.js) ejecutar una función que me reduzca el peso de esa imagen lo máximo posible y luego guardarla.

Gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar.

Saludos!